# How does fcm notification works when app is swiped from task manager

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As I understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936888/differentiate-between-android-killing-the-app-and-user-swiping-it-off-on-the-rec), swiping the app from the recent tasks kills it. In that case how can fcm still send notification to apps killed in that matter ?

On some devices [that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602194/not-receiving-any-notification-from-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-when-applicatio), so surely some app process is still running to receive these data notifications.

Answer (score 4):

On Android, Firebase Cloud Messaging works in tandem with Play services, which runs in a privileged process that can't be killed.  It's responsible for receiving the message and passing that along to the destination app.

Comment: so what happens with devices like huawei when notifications don't work. They remove that privileged process by default ?

Comment: Firebase isn't supported on devices without Play services.

Comment: is huawei y7 supported because I have white listed the app but still nothing

Comment: I don't know anything about that device.  This sounds like a whole different question than the one you originally asked.